# How do I install gcc-5.3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, ppa, gcc

I'm currently running `Ubuntu 16.04` and want to install `gcc-5.3` from source, without disrupting the`gcc-5.4` and `gcc-4.9` that I have already installed using Synaptic package manager.

The reason I want `gcc-5.3` is I'm using `CUDA 8.0 RC`, which doesn't support gcc versions after `5.3`. Rather than downgrading to `4.9`, I'd like to install (or at least know how to install) `5.3`. I already have the code for `gcc-5.3` and only need to go through the `configure/make/make install` ritual.

Now, I need to understand the various configure options before running make and make install. I particularly want to be certain that I install `gcc-5.3` in the right place and don't interfere with my existing `gcc-5.4` and `gcc-4.9`.

I found one account of how to configure `5.3`, that was as follows:

```
 ./gcc-5.3.0/configure --disable-checking --program-suffix=-5.3 --enable-languages=c,c++,go,objc --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib prefix=/usr/local/gcc-5.3
```

Some of these options make sense, others don't. Specifically, the options I think I understand well enough to not mess myself up are:

```
--disable-checking: Will make the installation quicker, but at the risk 
                    of missing errors. Since I'm paranoid, I'll probably 
                    omit this option.

--disable-multilib: I don't understand this. I gather it has something 
                    to do with variations on the compiler's target machine,
                    but that's all I can gather. 
                    At worst, if I omit this option, I think I'll just
                    end up with some extra libraries, which doesn't seem 
                    so bad. Why do/don't I want to use this?

--with-system-zlib: Use the zlib that I already have with my system, 
                    rather than gcc's version. This seems reasonable to 
                    me.

--enable-languages=c,c++,go,objc: AFAIK, I'm really just interested in c & c++, 
                   so this option seems pretty harmless, although I might 
                   just use --enable-lnguages=all, since it can't hurt.
```

The options that do worry me are:

```
--program-suffix=-5.3: This seems just to add a -5.3 suffix 
                       at the end of the installation path, 
                       which is probably a good idea if I get the 
                       path right

prefix=/usr/local/gcc-5.3: This just seems to specify the 
                           installation directory and to make the 
                           --program-suffix=-5.3 specification 
                           redundant. However, it is the option that 
                           makes me the most uneasy.
```

When I do a `find . -name gcc`, the only relevant paths I see are `/usr/lib/gcc` and `/usr/bin/gcc`

In `/usr/lib/gcc`, there are two sub-directories - `i686-linux-gnu` and `x86_64-linux-gnu`, since I have a 64-bit machine, I looked in the x64 directory.

There, I saw a soft-link - `4.9.3`, that linked to a directory called `4.9`, that had files for `gcc-4.9`. Similarly, I saw a softlink called `5.4.0` that linked to a directory called `5`, that had files for `gcc-5.4`. So, I expect that I want to use `prefix=/usr/lib/gcc/5.3` and not use the `--program-suffix` option. Is this correct?

At this point, I'm just assuming that when I run make & make install that the `.a` & `.so` files will get placed in `/usr/lib/gcc/5.3` and that the executable will end up as `/usr/bin/gcc-5.3` and that I'll be able to use Ubuntu's update-alternatives to move among `gcc-5.4`, `gcc-5.3` and `gcc-4.9`

(Note: the reason I'm not using Synaptic is that it only provides gcc-5.4, which it calls gcc-5. Similarly, the ppa `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` refers to all versions of gcc-5.X as gcc-5, which also seems dangerous to use. I suspect the decision to refer to all minor versions of gcc-5.x as gcc-5 is the root of my problems)

Comment: my strong recommendation is to use docker or LXD container for such different "compiler environments". Makes it much easier to run different compiler setups and versions and you avoid to create a dirty host system.

Comment: I agree with @malo. Especially, I'm against `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`. That can cause a lot of headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I ended up using was Ubuntu's `update-alternatives`. See this link:

[installing-multiple-gcc-versions](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04/#installing-multiple-gcc-versions)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install gcc=5.3 from source in that case. You can use a conda environment (install [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) or [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux)) and install gcc_linux-64=5.3.