# How do I install gcc 5.3 on ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: apt, cuda

The reason I need gcc 5.3.1 or older is because CUDA 8 does not support anything newer yet. Its very similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811530/how-do-i-install-gcc-5-3-on-ubuntu-16-04) but not the same.

Initially I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5
```

But that installed gcc-5.4

I then added "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main" as a repo under software updates.

Then I tried.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5=5.3.1-14ubuntu2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-5 : Depends: cpp-5 (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.1-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.1-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libgcc-5-dev (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.1-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I resolve this so I can install gcc 5.3.1

Comment: Does it have to be a 5.x release, or just <= 5.3.1? AFAIK 4.7, 4.8 and 4.9 are all available direct from the Zesty repo

Comment: A VM with 16.04 works too. Xenial shipped with 5.3.1 by default. Unskilled users should NOT mix repos and packages from other versions of Ubuntu - that's a quick path to a hopelessly broken system.

Comment: @seeldriver It has to be 5.3.1 or lower is my understanding. I will look into using 4.7.

Comment: @user535733 If don't ever take the risk of breaking things I wont learn and become 'skilled'. This is not my main computer. Just one I am setting up to do some development where I needed CUDA. Also not sure how well CUDA works under a VM although I am aware it might be possible.